# Plotting two heatmaps using different scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Sample_ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("IgA_m", 
"IgA_p", "Lumen"), class = "factor"), OTU_index = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 
55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 
63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 
68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L), .Label = c("a2fb93085ef90d85ce26b60b12598198", 
"a71cdb983f4aa92f7986bbba79bdf852", "2a33800972eebfd8eb952c1e66d47923", 
"55cea1dcc86e10b108b9392c1d32db87", "020d9f81bef9262a3ab5071ca9511c1a", 
"0fb2db1ddef94c9151ddad4b89516c19", "b20b8aa4bd244d965316a278875a1469", 
"ba5f9431d97db7fbaa8125bd2a2ef414", "249db27ea543f4f74d96cd8a4d1f8a5a", 
"ed7c0c6d0b49bdf4219d0ba156862b2d", "1510c9ae07e70a0b279453e4ef862698", 
"5a50ef393bb47b0401a5921d42df3a13", "b21bbd9f9a9ee207b793d76c06672371", 
"77934d18d930c4602bc8c79b132a3d9c", "dbbe9d87d7d35308dd7446315a66e29f", 
"e6b05a69bc7fa8dc428caa3d409c9fbb", "42690539aa399c812b99bc18ad34b6b7", 
"208fbec6e805a6273bdcf5f3b0a4e856", "1de19b0d7a171cdd32b4dff524e87db2", 
"4768917a0a9d8ca21f0b5c512d4ef5df", "f24fb97f9535ab02ce6f7913c70cc0ee", 
"b3da3555cadd21fa9ee11c955ceefe6d", "7d1056cdb2c52aaeebcc69fae394fce9", 
"052ba7abaeaa968c4f79e3f97d1f0a2f", "df3d6113f855e22f2a6d44e60f01baa7", 
"888fba9f2214d28155e89e7bdbee45a6", "a9a0015052b629976dfce94f3aa37c1c", 
"81b3925347c6126f2dfaa1c52749e211", "c9d862665050f543bf49e721ec5d0d2d", 
"9ca6cddd0fe3d71c618b52d4facec414", "e8ffca4f94ec58f2799a41d7023f7374", 
"5bba94db59051b57f82f82af2657751b", "085414bbd6ff66ce28c6e72552f6fe1e", 
"694f413b53b76692d2bf1cd02091399c", "e94a9da4bdf2d1d6fd8b6216ea53a5ab", 
"96f1df5356b17e2d4b6eefc878357fcb", "ba049349b7b31b2a76dc7f469e70a455", 
"17f166c05517c7b5deedcb96caeaa6ce", "e0425c9f83aeb3182d39686eb4c33fd9", 
"2c1ca646f21790c9fd0d628144304151", "5fc798b1df3bcda5e68c5d88d8d39402", 
"8ae3caba9b8bffe6cd0720d0bf0861b7", "68fa6eb93675602681b474cb0ce9048b", 
"916170a0b9c8f238e0e4ba6fd9a4434f", "82d62beac2026a93c81370ae3be39703", 
"79a9d2c3929074a416360f2c49d9e818", "1099950f329f9b0cc24b900fcc0a0d89", 
"c4fb58da9aff3c83c971c488ebd3cb70", "2d54bddc534353d4747ec1ffe430dfd1", 
"0debac7bda0e8a1808ee18f1fa0fff95", "c052a9548dafdb7e60155e80657eceeb", 
"877750a0b70e44cb26d356108387972e", "31ee661ac8be6d9acf84ee644cabd521", 
"0f3d5ab93a1bdff74c4c3fbe0ad3206b", "b7409db20419d9921bb75f9b0129d9ad", 
"850fc8381d6fc19a74e163682a3c65f4", "455113c04ae870bb6358d28eece40b64", 
"b0527c0e6ebd8747711f456340f5cf72", "b058bab03adbc1c975eab1ae3d772d2c", 
"9d1231e9a3e3361b978bbff3c3b158a8", "08ed17794e8af08e5f0fb28b4e415a5a", 
"c0a472775f09ea4c7c8618c1cccaddfd", "0da03528d09c7777b72cdb2195beab99", 
"15ab7ca6d18b935e7cddb7196cc5f8e0", "bd01119f1696ad8fb3394d742090be40", 
"cd33d521d1dfcb297336e993ca998d2d", "2d257553a6e4a29d1049474d2805c1fb", 
"973360718cfb0d1806d43527cb25adb3", "4e237c595da5cb9529b22d4795613121", 
"b8aac847144c04285bc3bb3f60a2782f"), class = "factor"), Relative_abundance = c(0.00554796858996244, 
0.0106691703653124, 0.00921816319562991, 0.0243257084329123, 
0.0372994195971321, 0.0343974052577672, 0.0223625810856948, 0.0112666439057699, 
0.00674291567087743, 0.054711505633322, 0.0309832707408672, 0.0157050187777398, 
0.00657220894503243, 0.00367019460566746, 0, 0.00187777398429498, 
0.00273130761351997, 0.00844998292932742, 0.0290201433936497, 
0.0137418914305224, 0.0103277569136224, 0.0274837828610447, 0.0106691703653124, 
0.0103277569136224, 0.0326049846363947, 0.0134004779788324, 0.0128883578012974, 
0.0315807442813247, 0.00913280983270741, 0.0120348241720724, 
0.00256060088767497, 0.00708432912256743, 0.00324342779105497, 
0.00324342779105497, 0.00349948787982246, 0.047541823147832, 
0.0215090474564698, 0.0297029702970297, 0.0212529873677023, 0, 
0.00153636053260498, 0.00128030044383749, 0.0109252304540799, 
0.0145954250597474, 0.00904745646978491, 0.00751109593717992, 
0.00879139638101741, 0.00367019460566746, 0.0351655855240696, 
0.0355069989757596, 0.0257767156025947, 0.00324342779105497, 
0.00409696142027996, 0.00529190850119495, 0.000682826903379993, 
0.00204848071013998, 0.00230454079890748, 0.189143052236258, 
0.0617958347558894, 0.132297712529874, 0.0924376920450666, 0.0308979173779447, 
0.0656367360874018, 0, 0.00162171389552748, 0, 0.000682826903379993, 
0.00230454079890748, 0, 0.00349948787982246, 0.00443837487196996, 
0, 0.00580402867872994, 0.0217651075452373, 0.0114373506316149, 
0.00503584841242745, 0.0186923864800273, 0.00896210310686241, 
0.000853533629224992, 0.000426766814612496, 0.000426766814612496, 
0.0104131102765449, 0.0419938545578696, 0.0353362922499146, 0.00597473540457494, 
0.0268863093205872, 0.0202287470126323, 0.00196312734721748, 
0.00682826903379993, 0.00546261522703995, 0.00725503584841243, 
0.0127176510754524, 0.0166439057698873, 0.00213383407306248, 
0.00571867531580744, 0.00734038921133493, 0.000768180266302492, 
0.00358484124274496, 0.00375554796858996, 0.00119494708091499, 
0.0474564697849095, 0.111215431888016, 0.00674291567087743, 0.0122908842608399, 
0.0395186070331171, 0.000256060088767497, 0.00384090133151246, 
0.00384090133151246, 0.00213383407306248, 0.0099009900990099, 
0.00896210310686241, 0.00213383407306248, 0.00418231478320246, 
0.00264595425059747, 0.0258620689655172, 0.0408842608398771, 
0.0173267326732673, 0, 0.000597473540457494, 0, 8.53533629224991e-05, 
0.000597473540457494, 0, 0.00315807442813247, 0.00844998292932742, 
0.00486514168658245, 0.00110959371799249, 0.00512120177534995, 
0.000426766814612496, 0, 0.00264595425059747, 0.00136565380675999, 
0.00443837487196996, 0.00537726186411745, 0.0096449300102424, 
0.00213383407306248, 0.00776715602594742, 0.00367019460566746, 
0.00768180266302492, 0.00631614885626494, 0.00870604301809491, 
0, 0.00136565380675999, 0.00119494708091499, 0.00221918743598498, 
0.00503584841242745, 0.00896210310686241, 0.00290201433936497, 
0.00554796858996244, 0.00375554796858996, 0.00204848071013998, 
0.00256060088767497, 0, 0.00503584841242745, 0.00597473540457494, 
0, 0.00520655513827245, 0.00802321611471492, 0.00640150221918744, 
0.00853533629224991, 0.0154489586889723, 0.0342266985319222, 
0.00119494708091499, 0.00128030044383749, 0, 0.00460908159781495, 
0.00648685558210994, 0.00307272106520997, 0.00230454079890748, 
0.00230454079890748, 0.00238989416182998, 0.00375554796858996, 
0.00367019460566746, 0.00273130761351997, 0, 0.00119494708091499, 
0, 0.00204848071013998, 0.00554796858996244, 0.00512120177534995, 
0.00375554796858996, 0.00913280983270741, 0.000682826903379993, 
0.0117787640833049, 0.0152782519631273, 0.0119494708091499, 0.0251792420621372, 
0.0578695800614544, 0.0585524069648344, 0.00213383407306248, 
0.00580402867872994, 0.00597473540457494, 0.00691362239672243, 
0.00836462956640492, 0.00247524752475248, 0.0285080232161147, 
0.0248378286104473, 0.0138272447934449, 0.0156196654148173, 0.0122055308979174, 
0.00341413451689997, 0.0315807442813247, 0.0162171389552748, 
0.00734038921133493, 0.00204848071013998, 0.00580402867872994, 
0, 0.128798224650051, 0.134516899965859, 0.0687094571526118), 
    Taxonomy = c("f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-1", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-1", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-1", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-2", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-2", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-2", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-1", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-1", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-1", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-2", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-2", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-2", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-3", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-3", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculum OTU-3", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-3", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-3", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-3", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-4", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-4", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-4", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-5", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-5", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-5", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-6", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-6", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-6", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-7", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-7", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-7", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-8", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-8", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-8", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-9", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-9", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-9", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-10", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-10", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-10", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-11", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-11", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-11", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-12", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-12", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-12", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-13", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-13", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-13", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-14", "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-14", 
    "f_Muribaculaceae g_Muribaculaceae OTU-14", "f_Eggerthellaceae g_Enterorhabdus OTU-1", 
    "f_Eggerthellaceae g_Enterorhabdus OTU-1", "f_Eggerthellaceae g_Enterorhabdus OTU-1", 
    "f_Bifidobacteriaceae g_Bifidobacterium OTU-1", "f_Bifidobacteriaceae g_Bifidobacterium OTU-1", 
    "f_Bifidobacteriaceae g_Bifidobacterium OTU-1", "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-1", 
    "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-1", "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-1", 
    "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-2", "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-2", 
    "f_Desulfovibrionaceae g_Desulfovibrio OTU-2", "f_Moraxellaceae g_Acinetobacter OTU-1", 
    "f_Moraxellaceae g_Acinetobacter OTU-1", "f_Moraxellaceae g_Acinetobacter OTU-1", 
    "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-1", "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-1", 
    "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-1", "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-2", 
    "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-2", "f_Pseudomonadaceae g_Pseudomonas OTU-2", 
    "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-1", "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-1", 
    "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-1", "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-2", 
    "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-2", "f_Peptostreptococcaceae g_Romboutsia OTU-2", 
    "f_Anaerovoracaceae g_[Eubacterium]_brachy_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Anaerovoracaceae g_[Eubacterium]_brachy_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Anaerovoracaceae g_[Eubacterium]_brachy_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-1", "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-1", 
    "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-1", "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-2", 
    "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-2", "f_Clostridiaceae g_Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1 OTU-2", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-1", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-1", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-1", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-2", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-2", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-2", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-3", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-3", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-3", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-4", 
    "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-4", "f_Erysipelotrichaceae g_Dubosiella OTU-4", 
    "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-1", "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-1", 
    "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-1", "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-2", 
    "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-2", "f_Lactobacillaceae g_Lactobacillus OTU-2", 
    "f_Clostridiaceae g_Candidatus_Arthromitus OTU-1", "f_Clostridiaceae g_Candidatus_Arthromitus OTU-1", 
    "f_Clostridiaceae g_Candidatus_Arthromitus OTU-1", "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Incertae_Sedis OTU-1", 
    "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Incertae_Sedis OTU-1", "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Incertae_Sedis OTU-1", 
    "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Paludicola OTU-1", "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Paludicola OTU-1", 
    "f_Ruminococcaceae g_Paludicola OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Blautia OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Blautia OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Blautia OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-3", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-4", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-4", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-4", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_GCA-900066575 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_GCA-900066575 OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_GCA-900066575 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-5", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-5", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-5", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Marvinbryantia OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006 OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-3", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-6", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-6", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_uncultured OTU-6", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-4", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-4", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-4", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-5", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-5", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-5", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_A2 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_A2 OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_A2 OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-3", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Roseburia OTU-3", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-6", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-6", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-6", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-7", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-7", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_ OTU-7", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-1", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-1", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-2", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-2", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-3", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-3", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-4", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-4", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-4", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-5", 
    "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-5", "f_Lachnospiraceae g_Lachnoclostridium OTU-5"
    ), ICI = c(2.42168674698795, 2.42168674698795, 2.42168674698795, 
    1.58547008547009, 1.58547008547009, 1.58547008547009, 0.566666666666667, 
    0.566666666666667, 0.566666666666667, 0.574446680080483, 
    0.574446680080483, 0.574446680080483, 0.403973509933775, 
    0.403973509933775, 0.403973509933775, 2.03703703703704, 2.03703703703704, 
    2.03703703703704, 0.379365079365079, 0.379365079365079, 0.379365079365079, 
    0.390057361376673, 0.390057361376673, 0.390057361376673, 
    0.460820895522388, 0.460820895522388, 0.460820895522388, 
    0.345299145299145, 0.345299145299145, 0.345299145299145, 
    2.47457627118644, 2.47457627118644, 2.47457627118644, 0.840579710144927, 
    0.840579710144927, 0.840579710144927, 1.15536105032823, 1.15536105032823, 
    1.15536105032823, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 1.24651162790698, 1.24651162790698, 
    1.24651162790698, 1.53389830508475, 1.53389830508475, 1.53389830508475, 
    0.878828229027963, 0.878828229027963, 0.878828229027963, 
    1.17910447761194, 1.17910447761194, 1.17910447761194, 4.75, 
    4.75, 4.75, 0.318709312199264, 0.318709312199264, 0.318709312199264, 
    0.294850948509485, 0.294850948509485, 0.294850948509485, 
    6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 3.07692307692308, 3.07692307692308, 3.07692307692308, 
    2.13207547169811, 2.13207547169811, 2.13207547169811, 3.60683760683761, 
    3.60683760683761, 3.60683760683761, 3.58490566037736, 3.58490566037736, 
    3.58490566037736, 0.923076923076923, 0.923076923076923, 0.923076923076923, 
    3.71014492753623, 3.71014492753623, 3.71014492753623, 5.46875, 
    5.46875, 5.46875, 2.76744186046512, 2.76744186046512, 2.76744186046512, 
    1.61594202898551, 1.61594202898551, 1.61594202898551, 2.83720930232558, 
    2.83720930232558, 2.83720930232558, 5.30769230769231, 5.30769230769231, 
    5.30769230769231, 21.5238095238095, 21.5238095238095, 21.5238095238095, 
    1.91603053435115, 1.91603053435115, 1.91603053435115, 13.3333333333333, 
    13.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 1.77777777777778, 
    1.77777777777778, 1.77777777777778, 1.75625, 1.75625, 1.75625, 
    2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 1.77777777777778, 1.77777777777778, 
    1.77777777777778, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    12.75, 12.75, 12.75, 2.01851851851852, 2.01851851851852, 
    2.01851851851852, 4.17948717948718, 4.17948717948718, 4.17948717948718, 
    1.01869158878505, 1.01869158878505, 1.01869158878505, 7.25, 
    7.25, 7.25, 3.54838709677419, 3.54838709677419, 3.54838709677419, 
    1.74626865671642, 1.74626865671642, 1.74626865671642, 1.48648648648649, 
    1.48648648648649, 1.48648648648649, 1.28205128205128, 1.28205128205128, 
    1.28205128205128, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 2.1231884057971, 2.1231884057971, 
    2.1231884057971, 0.961538461538462, 0.961538461538462, 0.961538461538462, 
    1.35227272727273, 1.35227272727273, 1.35227272727273, 1.68571428571429, 
    1.68571428571429, 1.68571428571429, 1.06849315068493, 1.06849315068493, 
    1.06849315068493, 6, 6, 6, 1.84905660377358, 1.84905660377358, 
    1.84905660377358, 2.11904761904762, 2.11904761904762, 2.11904761904762, 
    1.20331950207469, 1.20331950207469, 1.20331950207469, 2.10172744721689, 
    2.10172744721689, 2.10172744721689, 2.31818181818182, 2.31818181818182, 
    2.31818181818182, 1.02205882352941, 1.02205882352941, 1.02205882352941, 
    0.89365671641791, 0.89365671641791, 0.89365671641791, 0.728571428571429, 
    0.728571428571429, 0.728571428571429, 0.543956043956044, 
    0.543956043956044, 0.543956043956044, 3.03030303030303, 3.03030303030303, 
    3.03030303030303, 1.05691732447029, 1.05691732447029, 1.05691732447029
    ), log10ra = c(0.541884787594397, 0.626772169138628, 0.607795952185991, 
    0.733759879184875, 0.789247162517067, 0.778732842567338, 
    0.722836906013381, 0.63384537936088, 0.567205955833149, 0.838977583545416, 
    0.765163129658852, 0.676960275274368, 0.563877265376823, 
    0.488248213214674, 0, 0.401253830798792, 0.449893467501365, 
    0.596500847422149, 0.756666009566708, 0.659626322851853, 
    0.622550274597037, 0.749605016352126, 0.626772169138628, 
    0.622550274597037, 0.771785839538234, 0.656360444565252, 
    0.651302201470655, 0.767642557569709, 0.606588391711598, 
    0.642407502866951, 0.441515604941631, 0.57361771904532, 0.47220166124379, 
    0.47220166124379, 0.482065529735304, 0.820743668609206, 0.71778522520248, 
    0.759685025053096, 0.716230574107135, 0, 0.375204403623903, 
    0.351536911441358, 0.629850854501911, 0.667448677867147, 
    0.605369492475359, 0.581211217799338, 0.601642581524833, 
    0.488248213214674, 0.781599968525378, 0.782854198716219, 
    0.741280894970928, 0.47220166124379, 0.502527629062907, 0.535750804852757, 
    0.269936080500819, 0.412548935562634, 0.427838565185445, 
    1, 0.854783721373689, 0.953598917611843, 0.907058790548849, 
    0.764805027873416, 0.862611318917239, 0, 0.382222967743517, 
    0, 0.269936080500819, 0.427838565185445, 0, 0.482065529735304, 
    0.5129181182154, 0, 0.547741953187165, 0.719321477627977, 
    0.635797473513792, 0.52931253591004, 0.699565181865743, 0.604139039519662, 
    0.298902749879816, 0.208924056379543, 0.208924056379543, 
    0.623618690627469, 0.804635771797665, 0.782228598397453, 
    0.55150487795812, 0.746751894581477, 0.709818810894964, 0.407024194773549, 
    0.568838830380635, 0.539872161001638, 0.576708622566162, 
    0.649571351629484, 0.684497642656212, 0.417848112759086, 
    0.545818780013519, 0.578226906714947, 0.28522571012363, 0.485193676640392, 
    0.491232524299065, 0.342580821578577, 0.820510403829639, 
    0.931065451579267, 0.567205955833149, 0.645140484124722, 
    0.796749488242631, 0.142612855061815, 0.494149766503173, 
    0.494149766503173, 0.417848112759086, 0.617072169991281, 
    0.604139039519662, 0.417848112759086, 0.505204256156608, 
    0.445772111352484, 0.741710025328337, 0.801159655560141, 
    0.689716911069039, 0, 0.252602128078304, 0, 0, 0.252602128078304, 
    0, 0.468739807689893, 0.596500847422149, 0.524835822805332, 
    0.332960731214854, 0.531494298441904, 0.208924056379543, 
    0, 0.445772111352484, 0.359914774001092, 0.5129181182154, 
    0.537827838201934, 0.613670792476166, 0.417848112759086, 
    0.585562859293158, 0.488248213214674, 0.584128460003446, 
    0.558718501190166, 0.600376114748707, 0, 0.359914774001092, 
    0.342580821578577, 0.422939424715127, 0.52931253591004, 0.604139039519662, 
    0.457763259686892, 0.541884787594397, 0.491232524299065, 
    0.412548935562634, 0.441515604941631, 0, 0.52931253591004, 
    0.55150487795812, 0, 0.533639997127196, 0.589773341305408, 
    0.560460967820901, 0.597805499759631, 0.674826334373143, 
    0.77808701131034, 0.342580821578577, 0.351536911441358, 0, 
    0.517817258685718, 0.562180354744063, 0.465183097124176, 
    0.427838565185445, 0.427838565185445, 0.43255951507885, 0.491232524299065, 
    0.488248213214674, 0.449893467501365, 0, 0.342580821578577, 
    0, 0.412548935562634, 0.541884787594397, 0.531494298441904, 
    0.491232524299065, 0.606588391711598, 0.269936080500819, 
    0.639615743335638, 0.673383966034968, 0.641483571458393, 
    0.738236592289583, 0.846262341038254, 0.847785077735185, 
    0.417848112759086, 0.547741953187165, 0.55150487795812, 0.57045142024726, 
    0.595182949656881, 0.437114782990735, 0.754354758929446, 
    0.736464389817486, 0.660430113747534, 0.676252852189011, 
    0.644235868513373, 0.478860136880362, 0.767642557569709, 
    0.681125717623333, 0.578226906714947, 0.412548935562634, 
    0.547741953187165, 0, 0.950118954782305, 0.955758345006882, 
    0.868550379231396)), row.names = c(NA, -210L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to construct two heatmaps with one scale that corresponds to the "log10ra" column and the other to the ICI column.

The desired table should look similar to this:

[image]

where IgA+ is IgA_p and IgA- is IgA_m and Total is lumen in my data.

Looking at previous posts, the best I could come up with is to construct two separate plots with geom_tile and then merge them with a package called "gridExtra".

Unfortunately, this works but far from what I wanted because the plots are never at the same size and high and they are far away, no matter how much I try to play with the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of two separate plots. Instead you could achieve your desired result using faceting like so:

1. Make two separate data frames. One containing `Taxonomy`, `Sample_ID` and `relative abundance`, the second containing `Taxonomy` and `ICI`.
2. Add an identifier column to these dataframes (I called it name) which could be used for faceting.
3. Additionally add a `Sample_ID` column to the second df and set its value equal to "ICI". Doing so allows us to to map `Sample_ID` on x
4. Make your plots via two `geom_tile`s, one for each df.
5. Make use of `ggnewscale` to allow for a second fill scale
6. The rest is styling via theme options, ordering of factors, ....

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d$Sample_ID = factor(d$Sample_ID, levels = c("Lumen", "IgA_p", "IgA_m", "ICI"))
d1 <- d %>% 
  select(Taxonomy, Sample_ID, Relative_abundance) %>% 
  mutate(name = "Relative_abundance",
         name = factor(name, levels = c("Relative_abundance", "ICI")))

d2 <- d %>% 
  select(Taxonomy, ICI) %>% 
  mutate(Sample_ID = "ICI", name = "ICI",
         name = factor(name, levels = c("Relative_abundance", "ICI")))

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Sample_ID, y = Taxonomy)) +
  geom_tile(data = d1, aes(fill = Relative_abundance)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "seq", palette = "Greens", guide = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = d2, aes(fill = ICI)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(type = "div", palette = "Spectral", guide = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top")) +
  facet_grid(.~name, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]